# X-Runtime header related attacks

Tags: security

There are various http header fields which provides some clue to the attacker. I wanted to understand that the header field 'X-Runtime', if present in the response header, will it give any clue to attacker? I read some where that the field can be used for DOS attacks but it is not clear as to how the same can be used for DOS attacks. It would be great if I get a clue in this forum.

Answer (score 3):

Wherever you read and whoever stated that `X-Runtime` can be used to deploy a DoS attack is completely wrong. `X-Runtime` is not even a standard response field as you can check on [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) (page 64). There is no way to use it itself as means to attack (DoS) a server.

However,  it is useful for  spiders searching for websites running outdated versions of technology which may contain security vulnerabilities. Thus, `X-Runtime` -and similar non standard response header fields- could rather be used  in the [intelligence gathering](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Intelligence_Gathering) phase for by a pentester or a malevolent user to see if it is possible to take advantages of the disclosed information.

Put it in other words. `X-Runtime` is not by itself a vector of a DoS attack, nevertheless it makes your server verbose and thus it increases the [attack surface](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Attack_Surface_Analysis_Cheat_Sheet) and that is the reason why servers administrators ask how to disable it ([Apache mod_headers not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/48885/apache-mod-headers-not-working))